# IPhone: TableView Add data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i'm making app that have table view and i cant add data in table view

I have table view in the .xip file named NewTable in .h file and this is the code that i'm using it in .m file(listData it's array):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self TestTable];
}

-(void)TestTable{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Vishal",@"Vinod",@"Sachin",@"Nilesh",@"Balu",@"Amrita",
                      @"susho",@"Akash",@"Nil",@"Lop",@"Koi",@"Absoulate",@"Dwalin",
                      @"Fili",@"Kili",@"Oin",@"Gloin",@"Bifur",@"Bofur",@"Bombur",nil];

    self.listData = array;
    [array release];
    self.listData= array;

    [self.NewTable reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    return [self.listData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

{{{{{{{{{{{Also when i add nslog in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it's not print anything in consol!}}}}}}}}}}}
{{{{{{{{{{{Also when i add nslog in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it's not print anything in consol!}}}}}}}}}}}
{{{{{{{{{{{Also when i add nslog in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it's not print anything in consol!}}}}}}}}}}}

Comment: Have you set your view controller class (the one with your posted code) as the table view's data source in IB?

Comment: Why do you set your listData property twice -- once before releasing array, and once after?

Comment: How can i but it Data source in code not in .xip file?

Comment: I see worked code use like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `UIViewController` and not `UITableViewController` you need to make sure your viewController conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` and to the `UITableViewDelegate`

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Next you need to actually set this view controller as the tableView's dataSource and delegate.
You can do this with IB by dragging the mouse from your tableView to your file's owner (that is the MyViewController)
Or do this in code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.NewTable.dataSource = self;
    self.NewTable.delegate = self;
}
```

Also in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, change the line

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] autorelease];
```

with

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Comment: You say that your cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called, is your numberOfRowsInSection get called?

Comment: No No one of theses tow called

Comment: call NSLog(@"%@", self.NewTable); in viewDidLoad, is it nil?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I typically see used to initialize the data.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.listData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Vishal",@"Vinod",...,nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Although, I think your issue is assigning to an array that is no longer being retained.